# MP3's lag and jitter regardless of the player I use

Tags: windows-7, audio, mp3, sound-card, mp3-player

I am having a great deal of difficulty in finding a solution to my problem.

When I play music on my PC it seems to lag and stutter or jitter every few minutes... it's as if I am using a turntable and the RPM's suddenly slow down and then speed up again to normal... and it is usually accompanied by a stuttering or jittering.

This problem ONLY affects mp3 files... (Video files of all formats play just fine) This is strickly a music or sound issue.

I have tried a variety of players (Winamp, Xion, GOM Audio, FooBar, WMP, Creative Media Center and a number of others) ALL of these players exhibit the same playback issue.

I have checked that all my drivers are up-to-date and have tried reinstalling the soundcard numerous times... No luck. The problem persists.

I am using a Creative SB 5.1 VX audio card and Windows 7 Professional (32 Bit)

Please help! I am frustrated beyond description!

Comment: Try some older drivers,maybe even for vista.

Comment: What's the driver version? Also, what if you convert some `.mp3` files to uncompressed `.wav`? Do you get the same issue?